# Can't import AutoItLibrary from RIDE

Tags: python-2.7, autoit, robotframework

I can install AutoItLibrary, while when import it from RIDE, it always shows red.

And the log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Initializing test library 'AutoItLibrary' with no arguments failed: com_error: (-2147024703, 'OLE error 0x800700c1', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._AutoIt = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line 81, in _fetch_keywords
    return get_import_result(path, library_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\libraryfetcher.py", line 20, in get_import_result
    lib = robotapi.TestLibrary(path, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 45, in TestLibrary
    lib.create_handlers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 102, in create_handlers
    self.handlers = self._create_handlers(self.get_instance())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 163, in get_instance
    self._libinst = self._get_instance()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 173, in _get_instance
    self._raise_creating_instance_failed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.py", line 227, in _raise_creating_instance_failed
    % (self.name, args_text, msg, details))
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: My environment is: python2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ActivePython instead of standard distribution.
Reinstall also "pywin32" app.
This solved my problem.